# How can I initialize ASP.Net Core Identity in a way where only User, Role, and UserRole entities are created?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using ASP.Net Core Identity in an ASP.Net Core 3.1 project that does not require claims, external logins, or anything beyond users and roles. What are the minimum modifications must I make to the default ASP.Net Core Individual Accounts project template's code to ensure that extraneous tables (AspNetUserClaims, AspNetRoleClaims, AspNetUserLogins, and AspNetUserTokens) are not created in my database by the initial migration?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible. I would suggest just scaffolding what you need and remove what you don't need in the code. If you ever need to add a role in the future it won't be much work